# ng-repeat with dynamic json data received as argument

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am triggering the angular function from javascript and trying to repeat a div. couldn't find index and the data returned from javascript as object.

```
  var app = angular.module('game',[]);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var json = [];
  $scope.setlobbyData = function(obj){
      $scope.json = obj;
      $scope.lobbyData = json;
  };
  });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="i in lobbyData">some data</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var ssr = {
    "0": {
        "tradeSpread": 0,
        "minBuyIn": 10,
        "minPlayers": 2,

    },
    "1": {
        "tradeSpread": 0,
        "minBuyIn": 10,
        "minPlayers": 2,

    }
};
angular.element($("#foreignExchangeMain")).scope().setlobbyData(ssr);
```

Comment: I agree with @Jax700303. You can only iterate over arrays or list using ng-repeat. The way you are doing does not satisfy the requirement, so i would rather just the way jax said it in above comment.

Comment: Change $scope.lobbyData = json; to $scope.lobbyData = $scope.json; wanted to edit but deleted instead, dah!

Comment: i could receive the data from js. But, ng-repeat doesnt show up the data added in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used $apply function to update anugular and things got updated

```
var scope = angular.element($("#foreignExchangeMain")).scope();
scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.json = ssr;
    scope.setlobbyData(ssr)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-if`, which will reflect in view when collection updates in controller:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in lobbyData" ng-if="lobbyData">some data</div>
```

Comment: Try this. use ng-if which will reflect in view when collection updates in controller.

ng-if="lobbyData".